# Npm versioning architecture fatally flawed

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting this error from npm:

```
Browserify Failed!: Path must be a string. Received undefined while parsing file:
```

Because browserify works fine on other dev environments around the office I pretty sure it is a npm version issue.  Most likely related to an older babel-core. (ref https://github.com/babel/grunt-babel/issues/56)

The fix is to update babel-core to at least 6.10.  Here is the list for babel-core.

```
├─┬ babelify@7.3.0
│ └─┬ babel-core@6.24.1
│   └─┬ babel-register@6.24.1
│     └── babel-core@6.24.1
├─┬ laravel-elixir@5.0.0
│ ├─┬ babelify@7.2.0
│ │ └── babel-core@6.7.2
│ └─┬ gulp-babel@6.1.2
│   └── babel-core@6.7.2
└─┬ laravel-elixir-vueify@1.0.6
  └── babel-core@6.7.6
```

I need to update the copies of babel-core under laravel-elixir only. So how do I do that?

> npm -v = 3.10.10
>
> node -v = v6.10.2

Comment: What `npm` version are you using? `npm` versions 2 and 3 have [different dependency resolution](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3) logic. That may cause the unexpected behaviours on different environments.

Comment: Have you tried running `npm update` in the project directory on your machine?

Comment: I manually edited the packages that were stuck on 6.7.2 to require higher versions, and reran npm install, and it throw a bunch of errors, but now it gulps.